# Check if logged in remotely

Tags: login, session

I don't know how to check in a `.bashrc` script if I am currently on a Unix computer with the GUI. Then, I should launch the browser.

If I am on Putty, I am not supposed to launch the web. Therefore, I got something like an error message.

Can someone give a hint please?

Comment: `[[ -n "$DISPLAY" ]] && xdg-open` ...

Comment: Thanks! If I am on putty, and I am not supposed to launch the web. Therefore, I got something like an error message. A hint for how to deal with it?

Comment: That's a different question. Ask it separately, but please be quite a bit more detailed. The exact message needs to be copied.